# Play Framework WebSocket disconnecting IE clients

Tags: scala, internet-explorer, playframework, websocket, akka

I've asked on the Play Framework forums, but figured I'd ask here as well for the additional coverage:

Using Play Framework 2.3, I have a WebSocket handled with an actor that I'm using to push "StatusUpdate" messages to connected clients:

```
def updateSocket = WebSocket.tryAcceptWithActor[StatusUpdate, StatusUpdate] { 
  implicit request =>
    authorized(Set.empty[SecurityRole]).map {
      case Right(user) => 
         Right({upstream => DashboardListener.props(upstream, user.dblocations)})
      case Left(_) => 
         Left(Forbidden)
    }
 }
```

Everything is working wonderfully, except...

When a user connects via Internet Explorer, and the IE window loses focus, within 20 or so seconds the WebSocket forcibly closes. Firefox, so far, seems not to exhibit this behavior. I used Fiddler to inspect the WebSocket traffic, and it looks like IE is sending a "pong" message after it loses focus:

```
{"doneTime": "02:08:39.462","messageType": "Pong","messageID": "Client.2",
"wsSession":"WSSession-1","payload": "", "requestPartCount": "1"}
```

Immediately, the server sends:

```
{"doneTime": "02:08:39.462","messageType": "Close","messageID": "Server.3",
 "wsSession": "WSSession-1","payload": "03-EB-54-68-69-73-20-57-65-62-53-6F-
 63-6B-65-74-20-64-6F-65-73-20-6E-6F-74-20-68-61-6E-64-6C-65-20-66-72-61-6D-
 65-73-20-6F-66-20-74-68-61-74-20-74-79-70-65", "requestPartCount": "1"}
```

I'm assuming that this is because my WebSocket doesn't know how to handle pongs (since I've declared incoming and outgoing traffic to be of the StatusUpdate type). Moreover, the client receives a closeEvent with code 1003 (The connection is being terminated because the endpoint received data of a type it cannot accept). I've done some research, and it seems that this ping/pong is supposed to keep the connection alive, but not be exposed to the API. Has anyone run into this before or know of a potential solution?

If it matters, the clients only receive StatusUpdates via this socket -- at no point is any sort of message ever explicitly sent on it. The StatusUpdate messages originate from elsewhere in my Actor system.

Comment: Check the frames transporting that data, are really a pong frame and a close frame? or are they data frames? http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.5

Comment: Ok, I just finished monitoring the traffic with Wireshark -- they really are pong and close frames. I've also verified that firefox does not send the pong frame (and hence does not receive the close frame).